# EF Code First DB Migrations: Unable to update database to match the current model because there

Tags: entity-framework, database-migration

Even though I have set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

I still get this error

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled.  Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.
>
> You can use the Add-Migration command to write the pending model changes to a code-based migration.

I tried Add-Migration followed by Update-Database, but still got this error.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had here was that the database class library dll was not being copied into the main project.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @bbodenmiller He\She copied it.